# Make kernel module for BeagleBoneBlack

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

I have a BBB with Linux pre-installed from the vendor. Here is output from uname -a:

Linux beaglebone 3.8.13 #1 SMP Wed Sep 4 09:09:32 CEST 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux

I am trying to make a Kernel Module, for example HelloWorld.ko for it. 
I cloned code from git://github.com/RobertCNelson/linux-dev.git and checkout origin/am33x-v3.8.  After I built a module on it and tried to insmod it on my BBB, I got error message:
Error: could not insert module Hello.ko: Invalid module format,

I double checked version of the kernel, it is 3.8.13-bone53. Is this the root cause? Where can I get the "exactly" matched kernel source tree for it? There is no version named 3.8.13 in my cloned git commit tree.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can take help from "Local Version" option from General Setup in kernel menuconfig.

Comment: Did you cross compile your ko? What is the host OS?

Comment: yes, I made a cross compile in Ubuntu.